# Why midiOutOpen returns 1 (=Unspecified error) in a UWP app?

Tags: uwp, midi, desktop-bridge, appx, winmm

As soon as I convert the app, the **midiOutOpen** function starts to return 1 on being called.

I declare it as:

```
VB
Shared Function midiOutOpen(ByRef lphMidiOut As IntPtr, uDevID As IntPtr, cBack As IntPtr, dwinst As IntPtr, dwFlags As UInt32) As UInt32
```

Is there a way to use *winmm.dll/midiOutOpen* from a packaged app(*.appx*) that can still be published to MS store? Or some other way to acquire the handle of the midi device (ID 0)?

Comment: So you are having a desktop app that used call this method successfully, right?  Then you converted this app to appx. Could you please tell me how do you package your desktop app?

Comment: Maybe this is the reason - I'm packing on an offline pc that hasn't been updated for around 5 years. Currently, I'm trying to get my hands on a wim expanded base image, but I find **Docker** to be a horrible app (not working). I'm thinking to put the wim image on the offline computer and then refer to it from Desktop Converter. I've already installed _Project Centennial_ on the offline machine. Am I going the right path?

Comment: Just tested... The same behaviour when packed by using VS2019 on a different machine. MidiOutOpen returns 1.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Yes, before conversion it returns 0 and a call to midiOutShortMsg produces sound. Addition to my previous comment: I did packaging from source with side-loading.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the **midiOutOpen function** and other APIs like **midiOutShortMsg function** do not work in desktop bridge apps.

Currently, we'd suggest you use the modern MIDI from [Windows.Devices.Midi Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Midi?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-22000). You could refer to the sample here:[MIDI sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/MIDI).